# Jackson : Losing type information

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am trying to serialize/deserialize the following

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IdBundleCombine.class), 
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IdBundleDistinct.class) })
public abstract class IdBundle
{
    String sharedId;
    Long   internalId;
    //getters
}

public class IdBundleCombine extends IdBundle
{
    //setters
}

public class IdBundleDistinct extends IdBundle
{
    //setters
}
```

with the following code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("foo.json"), someInstanceOfIdBundle);
```

Which produce the following (without type information as you can see):

```
{"sharedId":"foobar","internalId":1234}
```

So i get an error `missing property '@type' that is to contain type id` when I try to deserialize it.

I tried every combination of parameters for  `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` I could find without ever succeeding in getting the type information to show in my file. I also tried to play with the `@JsonTypeName` on the subType without results.

My only guess is that I am doing something wrong with the mapper, but I can't find anything on the subject since most of the people seem to either don't want the type information to show up in the json string, or to have problems with the deserialization process.

Comment: Your code produces `{"@type":"IdBundleCombine","sharedId":"foobar","internalId":1234}`, which is fine. Are you sure you compiled your code after the changes?

Comment: Indeed, the code I provided actually works. I was trying to serialize a Collection<IdBundle>. Since the error I was getting had nothing to do with collections, it never occured to me that it could be the source of my problems. Anyway, I got it to work now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I did try using the following annotation and it worked, even with the property tag.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'name' attribute to @Type for sub types and give 'property' attribute of @JsonTypeInfo any value of your choice. Class below

```
<!-- language: java -->
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "meta-type")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = IdBundleCombine.class, name = "bundle-combine"),
    @Type(value = IdBundleDistinct.class, name = "bundle-distinct")})
public abstract class IdBundle{
}
```

will produce following json in case it's IdBundleCombine
   `{"meta-type": "bundle-combine", "sharedId":"foobar","internalId":1234}`